# Why can't "PURE" be defined as a const set to 0 to identify pure virtual classes?

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

Trying to define keyword `PURE` as a const set to `0`, to be used as an identifier for classes that are an abstract data type. Why won't this compile? Per Meyers in "Essential C++, topic 1," I would prefer to use `const` as opposed to #define, like so:

```
const int PURE = 0;
virtual void myFunction() = PURE;
```

Alas, this throws an error (same on Apple LLVM 7.0 and gcc):

```
Initializer on function does not look like pure-specifier
```

Example follows, with three techniques labeled A, B, and C;

```
1. const int PURE = 0 will not compile
2. #define PURE 0 compiles and runs fine
3. Simply setting function = 0 (Stroustrup) works fine.
```

It's now set up use the `const` solution, and so will not compile.  Simply comment/uncomment lines 4, 5, 11, and 12 appropriately to examine the three different methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int PURE = 0;                  // Case B
// #define PURE 0                       // Case C

const float PI = 3.14159;

class Shape {
public:
//    virtual float area() = 0;     // Case A: Compiles
    virtual float area() = PURE;    // Case B: This does not compile
                                    // Case C: Compiles
};
class Circle: public Shape {
public:
    Circle(float radius):radius_(radius) {}
    float area() { return PI * radius_ * radius_; }
private:
    float radius_;
};
class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    Rectangle(float base, float height):base_(base),height_(height) {}
    float area() { return base_ * height_; }
private:
    float base_;
    float height_;
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Circle c(3);
    Rectangle r(3,5);

    std::cout << "Circle Area:    \t" << c.area() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rectangle Area: \t" << r.area() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pure specifier `= 0` is not really an assignment expression, it's just magic syntax, so you cannot replace the zero with a variable; the `#define` works fine because it works through raw text substitution before the actual compiler runs.

Comment: The `#define` works because it is processed by the preprocessor, so PURE is substituted by 0 and it is compiled like `virtual float area() = 0`

Comment: I'd like to reiterate the comment Brian made on his succinct answer. This is only a good idea in a code obfuscation contest.

Comment: Even if this could work, how would you indicate pure functions as in `__attribute__((pure))`? `PURE2`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The language grammar says:

```
pure-specifier:
    = 0
```

That is, only the tokens `=` `0` are allowed. You cannot put an *identifier* there.

`#define PURE 0` works fine because macro replacement happens before translation.

Comment: So then, if I want to use the keyword ``PURE`` as described above, I have no options; I must use ``#define``?

Comment: @kmiklas Yes, but you also just shouldn't do it. It will confuse people reading your code. They will wonder if `PURE` just means `0` or whether it invokes some other magic.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the answer and comment by @Brian, IMHO this is not a good idea to begin with. It's *less* readable to anyone who actually understands the language, adds absolutely nothing of value and serves no useful purpose. As a side note, the word "pure" in CS (esp. functional languages) is not *at all* synonymous with or equivalent to "pure virtual" as used in C++ (or things like "abstract" or "interface" in other languages), so throw in terminology confusion as a potential additional downside.

Some people used to want to transition to "C" from languages like Pascal with stuff like this:

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END   }
// etc...
```

It's messy. It's bad practice in any language.
In this case, you're using C++. So use C++ syntax. Embrace the beauty of the beast :)

Sorry, got too wordy for a comment so had to add as an additional answer, but @Brian's original answer is both correct & concise (and gets my vote).